# desinstalar RVM (administrador de versiones ruby) en mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

Estoy trabajando con Ruby on Rails y quiero cambiar de administrador de versiones Ruby. Estoy usando actualmente RVM.

Es un requisito desinstalarlo totalmente del sistema operativo para usar RBENV

¿como desinstalar RVM correctamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con `rvm implode` o `rm -rf ~/.rvm`, cualquiera de las 2 formas funcionará para borrar `rvm` de tu sistema.

Comment: Excelente, funciono sin problemas. Gracias @AlterLagos